# Keep multiple sheets visible when hiding sheets with loop

Tags: vba, excel

Currently, I use the following code to hide all sheets except for one (in this case `Sheet4`):

```
Sub LoopHideSheets()
    Dim b As Worksheet
    For Each b In Worksheets
        If b.CodeName <> "Sheet4" Then
            b.Visible = False
        End If
    Next b
End Sub
```

All this works fine so far.

---

Now instead of only keep `Sheet4` visible I want to keep multiple sheets visible. Therefore, I tried to change the formula to this:

```
Sub LoopHideSheets()
    Dim b As Worksheet
    For Each b In Worksheets
        If b.CodeName <> "Sheet1" Or _
           b.CodeName <> "Sheet2" Or _
           b.CodeName <> "Sheet3" _
           Then
            b.Visible = False
        End If
    Next b
End Sub
```

However, this code gives me runtime error 1004. Do you have any idea where there is a mistake in my code?

Comment: Not related to the runtime error, but you want `And` instead of `Or`, otherwise you'll still end up hiding sheets you want to keep visible. If you consider `Sheet1`, `b.CodeName <> "Sheet1"` is FALSE but `b.CodeName <> "Sheet2"` is TRUE - therefore the sheet will get hidden.

Comment: Switch the `Or` to `And` to keep sheet 1-3 visible.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the `Or` to `And` to keep sheet 1-3 visible.

The `<>` in `a <> b` negates that means it is the same as `NOT a = b`. This logically switches `Or` and `And`.